# reference a namespace in ascx

Tags: asp.net

I have added namespace in web.config pages section. Can use it in aspx not in ascx. What should I do ?

Update: have added System.Web.Security with import directive but still can't see User class in Intellisense why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some code to post?

Answer (score 12):

You should go with a [`@ Import` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Your.Namespace" %>
```

Comment: Hi thanks I've done as you said for System.Web.Security but still can't see User class in Intellisense why ?